# unable to implement multicluster fedeartion using kubefed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, federation

I am trying to federate multiple clusters (minikube on mac) using kubefed https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed.

With the latest version of helm (helm3) and Kubernetes none of the available examples works.

1. https://itnext.io/a-kubefed-tutorial-to-synchronise-k8s-clusters-86108194ed79

2.https://betterprogramming.pub/build-a-federation-of-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-with-kubefed-v2-8d2f7d9e198a

3.https://github.com/runyontr/kubefed-demo

Since tiller is missing in helm 3. all of the mentioned demos fails when we deploy kubefed using helm chart.

```
helm --kube-context cluster1 install kubefed-charts/kubefed --name kubefed --version=0.1.0-rc3 --namespace kube-federation-system
```

Is there a working example/demo available which can be used for the reference for helm3 and the latest K8.

My env details;

OS: Mac

Helm Version:
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.8.2", GitCommit:"6e3701edea09e5d55a8ca2aae03a68917630e91b", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.18.1"}

Kubectl version:

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.5", GitCommit:"5c99e2ac2ff9a3c549d9ca665e7bc05a3e18f07e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-16T08:38:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.3", GitCommit:"816c97ab8cff8a1c72eccca1026f7820e93e0d25", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-01-25T21:19:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: Few issues which i created : https://github.com/runyontr/kubefed-demo/issues/1

Comment: Hey, I just tried kebufed with kind and it works great.  
I saw some issues you opened and thinking it may relate to the `ApiEndpoint` field in `kubefedclusters` resource.
The `ApiEndpoint` should be pointed to your minikube docker container (control plane) IP.

Comment: Let me check on that.